# Add Windows Azure AD Tenant as an Identity Provider using OAuth 2 endpoint

Tags: azure, oauth, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory

Im trying to integrate Windows Azure AD Tenant as an Identity Provider.

In order to achieve this i was able to configure sample AD in azure
1. Add the Access Control namespace to the Windows Azure AD tenant.
2. Add the Windows Azure AD tenant to the Access Control namespace as an identity provider.

And azure provides OAuth 2 endpoint also. The Question with me is how can i get Token Endpoint URL, Client Id and client secret.

I really appreciate if you can point me how to get these values.

Thank You,
Dharshana.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not need to use ACS to integrate your application with Azure AD. Further, if your application is a web app and all you need is single sign-on integration then you don't need to use Azure AD OAuth either - SSO using SAML/WSFed/OpenIdConnect should suffice. 
However, if your web app needs to access web APIs on behalf of the user (like directory graph API or Office 365 APIs) or if you are developing rich-client/mobile apps that need to call your own APIs on behalf of the user, then you do indeed need to use Azure AD OAuth. This topic explains this pretty well: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn151122.aspx
If you do indeed need a clientid and client secret for your app, go to the app properties page in azure portal and get the clientid and create a key. If you haven't yet registered the app in Azure AD follow this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn132599.aspx#BKMK_Adding

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanx Dushyant, But what i really need is the add Windows Azure AD as an identity provider for third party Identity server. So im not directly integrating webapp with azure.

Comment: Dharshana, I'm trying to understand the trust chain: Is it yourapp->3rdpartyidp->azuread? If so, does the 3rdpartyidp allow configuring another idp? If so, on the azuread side, you can easily add an application (relying party) that represents the 3rdpartyidp and use the federation metadata of azuread directory to configure on the 3rdparyidp side. By the way, you still don't need OAuth or ACS for this.

Comment: ye Dushyant, Thats what im looking for. Ill try out the solution thanx